# How to compute sentence embedding from word2vec model?

Tags: python, nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec

I am new to NLP and I'm trying to perform embedding for a clustering problem. I have created the **word2vec** model using Python's `gensim` library, but I am wondering the following:

The **word2vec** model embeds the words to vectors of size `vector_size`. However, in further steps of the clustering approach, I realised I was clustering based on single words instead of the sentences I had in my dataset at the beginning.

Let's say my vocabulary is composed of the two words **foo** and **bar**, mapped as follows:

`foo`: [0.0045, -0.0593, 0.0045] 
`bar`: [-0.943, 0.05311, 0.5839]

If I have a sentence `bar foo`, how can I embed it? I mean, how can I get the vector of the entire sentence as a whole?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to average the vectors of all words in the sentence.

Comment: This was my first thought too. However, I have just realised that there is a Doc2Vec model that basically appends each word's vector. At the end, I would have to average all of the vectors appended by Doc2Vec I guess?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used doc2vec, so I can't answer the question in your comment. You may post it as a separate question to get answers to it.